# HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway + Kotlin + Azure

Tags: networking, jvm, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a JAR built from Kotlin source with Spring Boot on an Azure app. instance.  "It *used* to work".  In an effort to track down the problem, I've modified it to serve a static page of HTML.  When I browse to the page, the **server** logs this valid HTML document:

---

IIS Detailed Error - 502.3 - Bad Gateway

#### HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

##### There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

##### Most likely causes:

- The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
- A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

##### Things you can try:

- Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI application.
- Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this error.

##### Detailed Error Information:

Module   httpPlatformHandlerNotification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   httpPlatformHandlerMainError Code   0x8007042b
Requested URL   https://AZUREAPPINSTANCE:80/Physical Path   D:\home\site\wwwrootLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

##### More Information:

This error occurs when a CGI application does not return a valid set of HTTP headers, or when a proxy or gateway was unable to send the request to a parent gateway. You may need to get a network trace or contact the proxy server administrator, if it is not a CGI problem.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=502,3,0x8007042b,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

---

and the browser shows *The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.*

Usually that means that the app. can't talk to some other service but here it is serving a static page of HTML.  I *think* there is some network misconfiguration because if I go to https://ourapp/XYZ then the *Requested URL* is https://AZUREAPPINSTANCE:80/XYZ so something in the Azure network stack is rewriting the address (`https` on port 80!).

Comment: Does your Application contains `web.config` ? If yes, then check if you have any multiple handlers defined in it.

Comment: No, no web.config

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, even though I don't understand it.

Refer to the POM, posted in [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72283891/how-to-fix-a-sockjsmessagecodec-is-required-but-not-available).

If I remove the entire `<pluginManagement>` element, the deployed Azure app. works.